launchctl load and unload com.vivi.control.serviceAgent.plist get error 5: Input/output error
1、 my plist /Library/LaunchAgents/com.vivi.control.serviceAgent.plist like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.vivi.control.serviceAgent</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/yuellppa/Downloads/vivo_test</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>  
    </dict>
</plist>

when the label is other any name but not "com.vivi.control.serviceAgent", use
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.vivi.control.serviceAgent.plist

and

launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.vivi.control.serviceAgent.plist


is ok.
when label is "com.vivi.control.serviceAgent", launchctl load or launchctl unload get error 5: Input/output error.
use
launchctl list | grep com.vivi.control.serviceAgent 

get nothing, so has no conflicting service。
Can anyone help me take a look?
i'am set com.vivi.control.serviceAgent.plist  everyone can read and right
